# Why nginx alias returnes 404 on .php files?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, alias, phpmyadmin

This configutation works:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
   root /usr/share/;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           root /usr/share/;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   }
   location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
           root /usr/share/;
   }
}
```

But this returns 404 on every .php file(while .css/.txt works fine):

```
location /pma {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/pma/(.+\.php)$ {
            alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

    location ~* ^/pma/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
    }
}
```

Error log is empty.

Comment: I found the source of the problem with Richard Smith's answer. I had the   `location ~ \.php$ {` instead of redirect for pma/.php files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [catalogue of problems](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) with `alias` and `try_files`.

You might want to consider using your old configuration hidden behind an internal rewrite:

```
location /pma {
    rewrite ^/pma(.*)$ /phpmyadmin$1;
}
location /phpmyadmin {
    internal;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. All files mysite.com/pma/filname returns 404, even index.php.

Comment: Comment out `internal;` and make sure that `mysite.com/phpmyadmin/index.php` is still working.

Comment: In this case it works fine.

Comment: Very strange. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Is it possible to add some logs for this proccess?

Comment: The access log records the URL and the 404, while the error log records an [error] level message generated by `open()` listing the local pathname. This is just the default logging on my system.

Comment: @littleguga Further to my previous comment, adding `rewrite_log on;` will send details of the rewrite process to the error log.

Comment: Finally it works. Thank you so much! I added unique location for .php files(also with redirect) and it seems to be good.